# Is React HOC a pure function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

React HOCs are said to be pure functions. But don't we add some props to the original/base component and return a new enhanced component ?
So with this "adding" of props, how are HOCs still considered pure functions ?

Answer (score 3):

An HOC is a pure function because it has no side effects. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html):

> Note that a HOC doesn’t modify the input component, nor does it use
> inheritance to copy its behavior. Rather, a HOC composes the original
> component by wrapping it in a container component. A HOC is a pure
> function with zero side-effects.

A thing that I think seems a bit off about this way of thinking about an HOC is that props are being *added* to the input component. The input component is being *provided* with new props it could already accept, nothing about the component itself is being changed.

I keep coming back to this answer because I feel like a lot can be said about it, but think about a higher order function:

```js
  const higherOrderFunction = (pureFunc) => {
    const x = someWorkWithoutSideEffects;
    return pureFunc(x);
  }
```

We would say that `higherOrderFunction` is not only a higher order function, but also that it is a pure function, right? I think that this is pretty well analogous to exactly what an HOC is doing.