# Can this be an example for Higher Order Component in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can this be an example for higher order components in JS

```js
function f1(greet){
 console.log(greet);
}

let f2 = (f1) => { return 'shan' };

console.log(f2()); // 'shan'
```

Comment: You could remove `f1` entirely, and its reference, and the code would still work. So it doesn't actually do anything. All you're doing is returning a string from a function and logging it.

Comment: Do you mean higher order functions or components?

Answer (score 0):

No, Higher Order Components (HOC) is a technique/concept in React : https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html and your code snippet doesn't even include React.

#### Higher-order functions

Your example looks like you wanted to build a Higher-order function instead : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function as it looks like you wanted to take one function (`f1`) as argument, but since you don't even use it, `f1` can be anything, so it doesn't fit the definition.

You could make `f2` being a higher-order function by making this change in your example:

```js
function f1(greet){
 console.log(greet);
}

let f2 = (f) => { return f('shan') };

f2(f1);
```

Now `f2` takes one function as parameter, which fits the definition.

The Wikipedia page gives a [good example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function#JavaScript) of a higher-order function in JS that takes a function and also return a function :

```js
const twice = f => x => f(f(x));
const plusThree = i => i + 3;
const g = twice(plusThree);
console.log(g(7)); // 13
```

Answer (score 0):

HOC is a concept in React, Whereas a component transforms props into UI, a higher-order component transforms a component into another component.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66166856/5338672) answer For more information and [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) article of React Documantation.